# Google maps strange polygons on landscape when water visibility off

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make google map water background transparent so that it shows the webpage background. However when I turn water visibility off, parts of landscape Africa, Europe and Greenland become surrounded by strange polygons.

Here's a working JS Fiddle link for the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/kgo81ec8/1/

Below is the same code to reproduce the issue.

```HTML
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
          background-color:black;
        }

        #map{
          height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">

</div>

<script>
        testMe = function () {
            var styles = [{
                "elementType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off",
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }]
            }];

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom : 1,
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(40, -3),
                styles : styles,
                zoomControl : true,
                zoomControlOptions : {
                    style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                    position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                },
            backgroundColor:"blue"
            };
            new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        }

        testMe();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is a screenshot of the output.

[image]

Here's a link to test google maps styles online.
http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Any help is appreciated, I have been working on this simple issue for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Google Maps Javascript API v3 StyledMaps.

Issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 6217:    Bug: Basic Layerstyle option create artefact for Africa and Groenland](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6217)

("star" the issue for updates and to indicate interest in having it fixed)

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact issue that I have. It's been 2 years since it was reported and not fixed yet..

Comment: It only has 4 stars, the number of stars is one of the criteria Google uses to prioritize fixes.